# Plotting classification prediction (K-nearest neighbor)

Tags: r, classification

Im trying to plot my predictions using the k-nearest neighbor method but am unable to do do, I get an error message as seen below. Im sure it's something to do with how ive set up my plot but unsure as to how i need to change it. Dataset is here; https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GYnlsXgT2GS9ubeXq8Pm7iNUWDRGogU_/view?usp=sharing

```
 set.seed(20220719)

#splitting training and testing data
ii = createDataPartition(classification[,3], p = .75, list = F) 
#split the data using the indices returned by 
createDataPartition
xTrain = classification[ii, 1:2] #predictors for training
yTrain = classification[ii, 3]   #class label for training
xTest = classification[-ii, 1:2] #predictors for testing
yTest = classification[-ii, 3]   #class label for testing
 #set training options
#repeat 10 fold cross-validation, 5 times
opts = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', number = 10, repeats = 5)

 #find optimal k (model)
kmeans_mod = train(x = xTrain, y = as.factor(yTrain),    
         method ='knn',                               
         trControl = opts,                            
         tuneGrid = data.frame(k = seq(3, 10)))       

#test model on testing data
yTestPred = predict(kmeans_mod, newdata = xTest)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(yTestPred), as.factor(yTest))

#plot
plot(kmeans_mod, xTrain)
```

Gives the error message

```
 Error in if (!(plotType %in% c("level", "scatter", "line"))) stop("plotType must be either level, scatter or line") : 
the condition has length > 1

Im looking for an output like this;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Joe, we don't have access to your data. Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: The link should work now, i've allowed access

Comment: What do you want your plot to look like Joe? You have x and y variables and two factor variables (actual and predicted). There are a few ways to plot this, but it's not clear what you are looking for. Also, you haven't shown how you are splitting the provided data into train and test sets. Please could you let us know what type of plot you want, and show us the code you are using to generate xTrain, yTrain, xTest and yTest ftom the linked csv. Thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron This information should all be added to the question now. Hopefully that clears up what I'm searching for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a plot similar to the one in the question, you can create a grid of prediction points to produce the background classification map, then plot the test data on top using `ggplot`.

```r
# Create prediction data frame for test data
preds <- data.frame(X1 = xTest[,1], X2 = xTest[,2], Group = yTestPred)

# Create classification grid
gr <- expand.grid(X1 = seq(min(classification[,1]), max(classification[,1]),
                       length.out = 100),
                  X2 = seq(min(classification[,2]), max(classification[,2]),
                       length.out = 100))
gr$Group <- predict(kmeans_mod, newdata = gr)

# Plot the result
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(gr, aes(X1, X2, col = Group)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.6) +
  geom_point(data = preds, shape = 21, aes(fill = Group), 
             col = "black", size = 3) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Though you may prefer a raster:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(gr, aes(X1, X2, fill = Group)) +
  geom_raster(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(data = preds, shape = 21, col = "black", size = 3) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

And you may wish to color the test data points with their actual level rather than their predicted level to get a visual impression of the model accuracy:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(gr, aes(X1, X2, fill = Group)) +
  geom_raster(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(data = within(preds, Group <- factor(yTest)),
             col = "black", size = 3, shape = 21) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]